# Codeigniter Calendar within a div and changing month

Tags: php, codeigniter, calendar

I am trying to use the CodeIgniter calendar as an event calendar as part of a social network similar to Facebook. In the CodeIgniter manual for the calendar class, it gets you to call the `echo $this->calendar->generate()` method from within the controller. However I wish this to appear within a div tag on a tab on a page. Is it OK to use the echo within the view in this way?

Secondly the next_prev_url uses the url to load the next or previous month. However I already use the url for information about the user such as their id. When I try to use the calendar at the moment, it takes the user_id as the month or year parameter, giving me a view for April in the year 186 or something like that. How do I load the next or previous month without using the URL?

Comment: use jquery eventsCalendar

Comment: For second question use ajax to load the calendar. It will work without refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question: it's ok, it's your style. To separate logic even more from view, you can assign calendar to variable.

```
$data['calendar'] = $this->calendar->generate();
$this->load->view('myview', $data);
```

Second: I don't know exactly why you get user id inside calendar(maybe some unclosed quotes somewhere), but there's no need for another jquery plugin. I wrote something similar long time ago.

```
//my-calendar-button is inside calendar template
jQuery(document).on('click', 'a.my-calendar-button', function(e){  
e.preventDefault();
    var link=this.href; //set link to controller in calendar template
$.ajax({
    url: link,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        var result = $('<div />').append(data).find('.my-calendar').html();

        $('.my-calendar').hide().html(result).fadeIn();
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        alert("Sorry, there was a problem!");
    },
    complete: function (xhr, status) {
        $('.my-calendar').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

And controller code if you need:

```
 public function getCalendar($year,$month,$eventType)
{
    $events=$this->event_model->get_month_events($year,(int)$month,$eventType);
    $prefs = array (
        'template' => $this->getCalendarTemplate(),
        'start_day'    => 'monday',
        'show_next_prev'  => TRUE,
        'month_type'   => 'long',
        'day_type'     => 'abr',
        'next_prev_url'   => '/ajax/calendar/' //it adds year and month automatically
    );

    $this->load->library('calendar', $prefs);

    $data['calendar']= $this->calendar->generate($year,$month,$events);
    return $this->load->view('/ajax/calendar',$data);
}

public function getCalendarTemplate()
{
    return $template = '

{table_open}<table>{/table_open}

{heading_row_start}<tr>{/heading_row_start}

{heading_previous_cell}<th><a class="my-calendar-button" href="{previous_url}">&lt;&lt;</a></th>{/heading_previous_cell}
{heading_title_cell}<th colspan="{colspan}">{heading}</th>{/heading_title_cell}
{heading_next_cell}<th><a class="my-calendar-button" href="{next_url}">&gt;&gt;</a></th>{/heading_next_cell}

{heading_row_end}</tr>{/heading_row_end}

{week_row_start}<tr>{/week_row_start}
{week_day_cell}<td>{week_day}</td>{/week_day_cell}
{week_row_end}</tr>{/week_row_end}

{cal_row_start}<tr>{/cal_row_start}
{cal_cell_start}<td>{/cal_cell_start}

{cal_cell_content}<a href="{content}">{day}</a>{/cal_cell_content}
{cal_cell_content_today}<a href="{content}">{day}</a>{/cal_cell_content_today}

{cal_cell_no_content}{day}{/cal_cell_no_content}
{cal_cell_no_content_today}{day}{/cal_cell_no_content_today}

{cal_cell_blank}&nbsp;{/cal_cell_blank}

{cal_cell_end}</td>{/cal_cell_end}
{cal_row_end}</tr>{/cal_row_end}

{table_close}</table>{/table_close}
';

}
```